# Relativelayout not wrapping its content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-wrap-content

I want my inner `RelativeLayout` to wrap it's content and stay below the `View` element. Why isn't it behaving like the pic below?

**My layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ebebeb">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView13"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_m_send" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: because your `View` width and height are both set to `match_parent` so there is not any space for your `RelativeLayout`

Comment: No use bro. setting it's height to anything won't do the trick.

Comment: try this:
set your `View` height to something, for example 100dp and then set your `RelativeLayout` layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" and I think It'll work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from both your `EditText` and `ImageView` will solve your proble.

Your `RelativeLayout` already have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and if you will set same for it's child also it will set layout height to full screen.

> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of
>   the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you
>   cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a
>   child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM

[Class Document](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Comment: but how to set it's child to stay at bottom?

Comment: It will stay bottom only, because it's parent layout is in bottom, check class document in edited answer

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <View
    android:id="@+id/relChart"
    android:layout_above="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relChart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
   >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivSend"
        android:background="@drawable/border_round_white3"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:maxLength="140"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSend"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/send_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```